# QML Connections handle event from service results in segfault

Tags: qt, qml

I am having a hard time getting to understand the non-standard C++ world that is qt. I have a class that can emit a 'login' signal, that I want to listen to from QML, this simply segfaults.

```
class Service : public QObject
Q_OBJECT
{
public:
    Service()
    {
        // get the context, snipped for brevity
        rootContext->setContextProperty("service", this);
    }
public signals:
    void login(bool succcess);
public slots:
     void method();
};
```

I can successfully call 'service.method' from the QML, but if I add a Connections section to listen for the login event, I get a segfault whenever that component is displayed.

```
Page {
    Component {
        Column {
             ...
            Connections {
                target: service
                onLogin: {
                    console.login("TEST");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried moving the 'Connections' section out of the columns, but this results in a runtime-error and a white page, because it fails to parse the QML. What am I missing here?

I am using QT Creator 4.2.1 if that is in any way relevant.

Comment: Does service perhaps live in another thread?

Comment: No. The whole application is as single-threaded as they come.

Comment: what is `console.login`? did you mean `console.log()`? And I don't think that placing the `Connections` inside `Component` is a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. Apparantly you cannot have a slot and a signal by the same name - even if they have wildly different function signatures. It doesn't give a compile error, it simply crashes.

After changing the name of the signal it magically started working.